How to create a dictionary with initial values using collection expressions?
C# 12 introduced collection expressions and now you can write code like List<int> l = [1, 2, 3];.
When it comes to using them with dictionaries, it seems to work fine when creating an empty one with Dictionary<string, int> d = [];.
However, when it comes to creating one with initial values, none of these seem to compile:

Dictionary<string, int> d = [{ "a", 1 }];
Dictionary<string, int> d = [("a", 1)];
Dictionary<string, int> d = [new KeyValuePair<string, int>("a", 1)];

Is there a way I can create a dictionary containing initial values using collection expressions?

Dictionary<TKey,TValue> has always had an initializer syntax (since its birth in 2005). It has picked up another since then. It doesn't need a third one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer

@Flydog57 I'm aware about the collection initializer syntax, it's what inspired the first of the three attempts listed in the question. Here I'm talking about C# 12's collection expressions specifically. Otherwise I'd probably just be duplicating Proper way to initialize a C# dictionary with values

Dictionary<string, int> d = [new KeyValuePair<string, int>("a", 1)]; yields this error message:

Collection expression type 'Dictionary<string, int>' must have an instance or extension method 'Add' that can be called with a single argument.

It leads to a solution to make it compile: creating the following extension method
public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> added)
{
    source.Add(added.Key, added.Value);
}

Note that this extension method will also enable the usage of spread elements with dictionaries like Dictionary<string, int> d2 = [..d];

Similarly, based on the above error message, one might expect the same kind of extension method using a tuple (so (TKey Key, TValue Value) instead of KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>) to enable Dictionary<string, int> d = [("a", 1)]; but (because Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> and not IEnumerable<(TKey, TValue)>, more here) it will instead yield:

CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type '(string, int)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>'


Note that this self-answer is just for completeness but it isn't a satisfying solution to me as having to type KeyValuePair<string, int> for each entry makes it super lengthy

this convenience method will alleviate some of the pain I think public static class New{  public static KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> Kvp<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, TValue value) => new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(key,value); }

You can use target-typed new to simplify that: Dictionary<string, int> d = [new("a", 1)];

@nalka also new KeyValuePair<string, int>(...) -> KeyValuePair.Create(...) can be used in addition to the target typed new.
